# stdout progress bars don't work in Pycharm

Tags: intellij-idea, console, progress-bar, pycharm, stdout

Many programs display progress bars by printing to stdout and then returning to beginning of line and printing again. This way they can achieve realtime progress bar appearence.

Unfortunately, in many cases this functionality does not work in PyCharm's console.

This is an example on how it shows keras train progress bar:

[image]

i.e. each progress bar change goes to separate line.

Is it possible to fix this?

Comment: Console is not a real terminal, you could try the "Emulate terminal in output console" option.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

[CrazyCoder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/104891/crazycoder)'s comment is the right way to go.

I just formalize his comment as an answer here.

---

### Step1: Go to `Run` ---> `Edit Configurations`

[image]

### Step2: Check the option: `Emulate terminal in output console`

[image]

### Voilà

[image]

Comment: But I can't run with Python console when I select this option, if I want check variables after run code, this way is not going to work...

Comment: **for people using PyCharm Edu**, which doesn't have the "Run" menu, you can access your Run configurations via Help --> Find Action --> Type "Edit Configurations" (source: [jetbrains.com](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000561524-Pycharm-Edu-version-has-no-Run-menu-))

Comment: This option is no longer present in 2020.1.

Comment: Option is present in 2020.2

Answer (score 5):

Emulate terminal in output console is gone from PyCharm 2022.2.1 (Professional Edition).  Other suggestions?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The only way I managed to get progress bars (I'm using tqdm 4.19.5 for a progress bar, PyCharm Community 2017.3.2 and Anaconda/Python 3.6.3) to work correctly was to uncheck the "Show command line afterwards" option:

[image]

[image]

[image]

The solution posted by Tay2510 (checking the "Emulate terminal in output console" option) didn't work for me.

One downside of my solution is that you lose console access after your script is done running.

Comment: It looks like jetbrains took out the "Show command line afterwards" option. I don't see it anymore.